# react-native-draggable-flatlist drag/drop reseting when used with shouldComponentUpdate

Tags: javascript, react-native, user-interface, react-redux, react-native-draggable-flatlist

I am working on a react-native application where I am using react-native-draggable-flatlist for one of the list and unfortunately I have to use shouldComponentUpdate in the component for data manipulation from other list item on another component, but after adding the  shouldComponentUpdate, my drag/drop is not not working, I can able to drag and drop but it immediately resets the whole list to original positioning set.

Please help me with some suggestions to make the drag/drop work along with shouldComponentUpdate as I don't want to break the existing functionality

Code

```
<DraggableFlatList
 scrollPercent={5}
 data={testData}
 renderItem={this.renderItem}
 keyExtractor={item => `item-${testkey}`}
 onMoveEnd={({ data }) => {
   this.setState({ data });
 }}
/>

public shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps, nextState) {
  if (nextProps.data.length !== nextState.data.length) {
     this.setState({
       data: nextProps.data
     })
   }
   return true
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`shouldComponentUpdate` is not intended for doing sideEffects.It is used to reducer render count for prop changes for performance benefit.
shouldComponentUpdate should return true or false determining whether component should rerender.

[shouldComponentUpdate](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#shouldcomponentupdate)

You may use `componentDidUpdate` which fires after prop changes reflect or `componentWillReceiveProps` which fires before prop reflects

I recommend using `componentDidUpdate` like

```
componentDidUpdate  = (prevProps, prevState) => {
  if (this.props.data.length !== this.state.data.length) {
     this.setState({
       data: nextProps.data
     })
   }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't be using `shouldComponentUpdate` for this purpose. If you're just copying `props.data` into `state.data`, why not just use `props.data` directly?

If it's absolutely necessary that you do the copying on every update, then consider using another lifecycle method, like `componentDidUpdate` or `getDerivedStateFromProps`. You could also use `componentWillReceiveProps`, but it has been deprecated and should be avoided.